# Scope and variable types in Razor pages (corrected)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, scope, razor-pages

Another beginner's question. I've captured a value from a dropdown using a JavaScript function and am trying to use it on my page. However, my return value (LocationID) is the wrong data type and the code won't compile. (When I tried the "if" line below as *if (pc.LocationID = Model.BookingSL.SelectedValue)* I got a message to that effect. I've tried to do a typecast to put the number into a string but nothing seems to work.

The following gives "The name 'LocSelected' does not exist in the current context", whether or not I prefix LocSelected with an @. I don't understand what's happening with the variable scope, as everything I've read tells me that a public property should be available elsewhere on my page/page model.

Have I missed something obvious again? How can I compare the value from my selectlist with a field value from my other current table entity (PCList)? (Is *Selectlist.SelectedValue* even the correct property of a SelectList to get the single selected value?)

In Home.cshtml.cs

```
namespace Bookit.Pages
{
    public class HomeModel : PageModel
    {
        ..
        [BindProperty (SupportsGet= true)] public string LocSelected {get; set; }
```

In Home.cshtml

```
    {
       LocSelected = pc.LocationID.ToString();  
       if (LocSelected == Model.BookingSL.SelectedValue.ToString())
       { // filter the following data shown
```

I would be grateful for any hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be getting hung up on how the model binds up to the page. Inside your @{  } block on your Home.cshtml page, you should have a property available called `Model` (upper case), and THAT property should then have the `LocSelected` property available, at least as I read your code.

Then for your comparison to filter the data, for standard Razor Pages you either need to work it out with JS or JQuery on the page, or set up a GET request back to the server with a search value, with a response that has your updated list. AJAX with API endpoints is another good alternative, and you could possibly include Razor Components (Blazor), which will allow for some richer client side interactions without Javascript, and can be used inside RazorPages applications.

Depending on your comfort level with JS and JQuery and the related DOM manipulation, that might be your ticket. Use the GET method to get your initial, use client side tech to do what you need to do, then POST it back when you are done, hence less trips to the server.

Comment: Thanks Nik. I found a few errors in my logic. Thought I had already tried _Model.LocSelected_ but obviously not, since that got me over the initial problem. I'm still stuck on the comparison because my SelectList is initially empty but apparently isn't null, and trying to check whether its count is greater than zero gives me _"Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group'"_.